# Problema con UTF-8

Tags: html

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?
En mi localhost me sale normal, de esta manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero una vez que lo subo al hosting, me sale de esta manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea principal fue cambiar el utf-8 en las tablas, pero tanto como en mi localhost como en el hosting el cotejamiento es el mismo... entonces no se que hacer :/

Comment: ¿Y el código html donde estas haciendo todo esto?

Comment: es este.

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

Comment: Lo checare, gracias!